# Performance report for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, performance, awr, statspack

Oracle creates nicely HTML-formatted workload reports (AWR) that list things like instance statistics, wait events, the top ten heavy SQL statements (by number of executions, number of disk reads, and so on).

Is there a similar tool for Postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And another one - [pgFouine](http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/).

Also take a look at what's under [Database Administration](http://pgfoundry.org/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=317) on [PgFoundry](http://pgfoundry.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Not an HTML-report, but a top-like tool for pgsql: http://ptop.projects.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 1):

The description says:
"PoWA is PostgreSQL Workload Analyzer that gathers performance stats and provides real-time charts and graphs to help monitor and tune your PostgreSQL servers.

It is similar to Oracle AWR or SQL Server MDW."

http://dalibo.github.io/powa/

Answer (score 0):

I found another one that looks promising: [pgstatspack](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgstatspack).

Also http://www.postgrestats.com/